# R: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I'm a new programmer. This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(pastecs)
library(psych)


#loading in the data
setwd("D:\\Meus Documentos\\Spider2099\\IC\\Analise de dados-Glandula\\Scripts R\\Histogram")
hist<-read.delim("adultos.txt", header=T)

#setting up the histogram
NormDist<- ggplot(hist,aes(Adultos_1))+ theme(legend.position = "none")+ geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour = "black", fill = "white")
labs(x= "Log2(ratio H/L) Tecnical replicate 1", y= "Density")

#fitting a normal curve
NormDist+stat_function(fun=dnorm, args=list(mean=mean(hist$Adultos_1,na.rm=T),sd=sd(hist$Adultos_1,na.rm=T)),colour = "black", size=1)

*****Warning message:
In mean.default(hist$Adultos_1, na.rm = T) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA*****
```

How can I solve this trouble?

Comment: class(hist$Adultos_1)? Change this column to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

try mean(as.numeric(hist$Adultos_1),na.rm=T)?

OR I'd suggest not to call it 'hist' but hist1.